# How to use parameter variable in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to xslt so please let me know whats wrong with my syntax here. If I compare with a Constant value of '880.50' I get the desired result. But if I try to do the samething with parameter being passed I get nothing. The code snippet is as under.

```
<xsl:template name="ShowJourneyLegs" >
  <xsl:param name="TotalFare" />  
    <Key4><xsl:value-of select='$TotalFare'/></Key4>   
    <JourneyLegKeys><xsl:value-of select="/FareSearchResponse/CompleteItineraryFares/AirFare[@Total = '880.50']/JourneyLegKeys/Key[1]"/></JourneyLegKeys>
     <JourneyLeg><xsl:value-of select="/FareSearchResponse/CompleteItineraryFares/AirFare[@Total = '$TotalFare']/JourneyLegKeys/Key[1]"/></JourneyLeg>  
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You need to format your code by indenting it with 4 spaces or it will not display correctly.

Comment: Good Question (+1). See my answer for an explanation and solution of the problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the apostrophes from around the $TotalFare.  The last XPath should look like this: `/FareSearchResponse/CompleteItineraryFares/AirFare[@Total = $TotalFare]/JourneyLegKeys/Key[1]`

Inside of an XPath expression, you only use apostrophes for literals.

Answer (score 0):

> I am new to xslt so please let me know
>   whats wrong with my syntax here.

**The problem is in this instruction**:

```
<xsl:value-of select=
      "/FareSearchResponse/CompleteItineraryFares
                              /AirFare[@Total 
                                      = '$TotalFare']/JourneyLegKeys/Key[1]"/>
```

You are not comparing to the value of the `$TotalFare` but to the *string* `'$TotalFare'`.

**Solution**: Remove the apostrophes that surround `$TotalFare`.